# Is addition of Custom field in Custom object possible using MetaData API

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, update

After creation of a `Custom object` metadata with *createMetadata(...)*,
I want to add new lookup `Custom Field` to it additionally (not at the time of creation).

By using *updateMetadata(...)* method, I attach the `Custom field` details in analogy to like when creating a new `Custom object` with `Custom field`,

I get successful response with no error for the metadata update,

but new `Custom field` is not added in Salesforce to the existing Custom object.

By *updateMetadata(...)* I can change static fields of the `Custom Object`, like `Description`, etc.. but I cannot add an additional custom field by applying its description in the *fields* array.

Can anyone advise is it possible to additionally append a new custom field after creation of `Custom object` using *updateMetadata* and what's the trick, if possible.

If it's impossible to additionally append a new custom field, please confirm that.

PS: With the same meta description of the new field I can add it at creation time with no problem, but not at update time.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by creation of field specifying CustomObjectName.FieldName fullname.
Update is not the right method, create will do the job.